# distutils wildcard entry for include_dir

Tags: python, wildcard, packaging, distutils

I am setting up a package using distutils.

I need to allow access to a module that is built during the set-up process and is located in `./build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6`. I do this by including the

```
include_dirs=["./build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6"]
```

when adding the extension to the distutils Configuration.

My question is there a way of setting this using a wildcard such as:

```
include_dirs=["./build/temp.linux*"]
```

as when I try this it fails, citing error:

```
Nonexistent include directory ‘build/temp.linux*’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
```

The reason I want this is that the build folder will be named differently depending on the system. Alternatively if anyone knows a way of figuring out what this temp build folder will be called that would also work.

Comment: You probably need [distutils.core.Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdistutils%5D+extension+module).

Answer (score 0):

The way I have got around this problem is as follows:

```
def return_major_minor_python():

    import sys

    return str(sys.version_info[0])+"."+str(sys.version_info[1])


def return_include_dir():
    from distutils.util import get_platform
    return get_platform()+'-'+return_major_minor_python()
```

Then when calling `config.add_extension()` using:

```
include_dirs=['build/temp.' + return_include_dir()]
```

So the whole process for adding a f90wrapped, f2py extension to a python package is:

```
def setup_fort_ext(args,parent_package='',top_path=''):
    from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
    from os.path import join
    import sys

    config = Configuration('',parent_package,top_path)
    fort_src = [join('PackageName/','fortran_source.f90')]

    config.add_library('_fortran_source', sources=fort_src,
                         extra_f90_compile_args = [ args["compile_args"]],
                        extra_link_args=[args["link_args"]])

    sources = [join('PackageName','f90wrap_fortran_source.f90')]

    config.add_extension(name='_fortran_source',
                      sources=sources,
                      extra_f90_compile_args = [ args["compile_args"]],
                      extra_link_args=[args["link_args"]],
                      libraries=['_tort'],
                      include_dirs=['build/temp.' + return_include_dir()])

    return config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import subprocess
    import os

    install_numpy() #installs numpy 
    install_dependencies() #calls to pip to install any requirements

    from numpy.distutils.core import setup

    config = {'name':'PackageName',
              'version':__version__,
              'project_description':'Some Package description',
              'description':'Some package Description',
              'long_description': open('README.txt').read(),
              'long_description_content_type':'text/markdown',
              'author':'Your name here',
     'author_email':'your email here',
     'url':'link to git repo here',
     'python_requires':'>=3.3',
     'packages':['PackageName'],
     'package_dir':{'PackageName':'PackageName'},
     'package_data':{'PackageName':['*so*']},
     'name': 'PackageName'
      }


    config_fort = setup_fort_ext(args,parent_package='PackageName',top_path='')
    config2 = dict(config,**config_fort.todict())

    setup(**config2)
```

where the source fortran_source.f90 is wrapped beforehand and the resulting wrapped source file (*f90wrap_fortran_source.f90*) is included as a library, and subsequently compiled by f2py.

args in the above is just a dict with the any linking or compile args you wish to pass through.